# Can mapEventToState same instance

Tags: flutter, bloc

Must we create new instance of state in mapEventToState ?
like https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_form_validation/lib/bloc/my_form_bloc.dart#L31 we have a `copyWith`

If we simply do

```
state.email=event.email;
yield state;
```

What happens? no update in UI?

What if we have nested objects? `state.a.b.c` , how many copyWith required?

I am using `swagger-codegen` , so `a` and `b` and `c` has no copyWith methods , it's too cumbersome to implement copyWith for all of my generated objects

How can I change a properties easily?

Comment: If you don't want to make a new instance in your bloc, don't make your Object class extends `Equatable`.

Comment: Can you show me how? How you update state.a.b.c? How you create your State object?